# Wait unitl ListView's smoothScrollToPosition() finishes

Tags: android, listview, smooth-scrolling

### Scope

I need to scroll to certain position smoothly and then "jump" to another position with `setSelection(anotherPosition)`. This is done to create an illusion of smooth scrolling of (e.g.) 100 items in `ListView`. `smoothScrollToPosition(100)` lasts too much, you know.

### Problem

`setSelection()` doesn't wait till `smoothScrollToPositio`n finishes its work, so `setSelection()` is being called immediately and user sees quick jumping only;

### Code

```
private final int scrollableItems = 20;

int firstVisiblePosition = mListView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
if (firstVisiblePosition < scrollableItems) {
    mListView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
} else {
    mListView.smoothScrollToPosition(firstVisiblePosition - scrollableItems);
    mListView.setSelection(0);
}
mListView.clearFocus();
```

### Idea

OK, we could change logic of smoothness illusion: first `setSelection()`, then scroll smoothly (we're scrolling to the very first item on top of the list):

```
    int firstVisiblePosition = mListView.getFirstVisiblePosition();

    if (firstVisiblePosition < scrollableItems) {
        mListView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
    } else {
        mListView.setSelection(scrollableItems);
        mListView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
    }
    mListView.clearFocus();
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
final ListView listView = ...;
View listItemView = ...;
listView.smoothScrollBy(listItemView.getHeight() * NUMBER_OF_VIEWS, 
    DURATION * 2);
listView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        listView.smoothScrollBy(0, 0); // Stops the listview from overshooting.
        listView.setSelection(0);
    }
}, DURATION);
```

Of course, direction of the scroll etc. would need to be adjusted for your use case (go to the top of the list)

**EDIT**: Old solution could overshoot if the velocity of the scroll was too high, smoothScrollBy(0,0) will stop the smooth scrolling before setting the selection properly and immediately.

Comment: But it could be a solution only for list with fixed height items. I think that  mListView.setSelection(scrollableItems);   mListView.smoothScrollToPosition(0); is still more preferable way ;)

Comment: Yup, its only used to get a suitably high speed. As long as you replace the height * NUMBER_OF_VIEWS with any other suitably large value (i.e. if your views are very varied in size) you will get a fast enough scroll that the user wont notice when you snap with setSelection(0) in the Runnable that is postDelayed to the ListView.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to add an OnScrollListener.

```
private final int scrollableItems = 20;

int firstVisiblePosition = mListView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
if (firstVisiblePosition < scrollableItems) {
    mListView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
} else {

    mListView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
      @Override
      public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView absListView, int i) {
        if (i == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
          mListView.setSelection(0);
           }
      }
   })

   mListView.smoothScrollToPosition(firstVisiblePosition - scrollableItems);
}
mListView.clearFocus();
```