# Android listview smothScrollBy with speed?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-scroll

Is there any way similar like using `smoothScrollToPosition` with control over speed or the time it takes to scroll smoothly?

Now i am using below snippet to scrool to `pos`

```
int firstVisible = lv.getFirstVisiblePosition();
int lastVisible = lv.getLastVisiblePosition();
            if (firstVisible > pos)
                lv.smoothScrollToPosition(pos, pos - firstVisible - 2);
            if (pos > lastVisible)
                lv.smoothScrollToPosition(pos, pos + lastVisible + 3);
```

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7928820/wait-unitl-listviews-smoothscrolltoposition-finishes) i modified to aabove snippet as below

```
    int childheight = lv.getChildAt(firstVisible).getHeight();

            if (firstVisible > pos)
                lv.smoothScrollBy(childheight*pos, 800);
            if (pos > lastVisible)
                lv.smoothScrollBy(childheight*pos, 1200);
```

But, i get nullpointer exceptions at

> ```
>   int childheight = lv.getChildAt(firstVisible).getHeight();
> ```

**Edit**

i am in need of scrooling automatically to a childView by a button press by user,say MENU button. I am not facing the problem of list scrolling slowly because of doing resource intensive task to populate listview. All i want is the functionality of `smoothScrollToPosition` with `smoothscrooltoPosition with velocity control`

Comment: I guest that you should use a Animation.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21588188/listview-item-scroll-animation-uikit-dynamics-like

Comment: @MiguelAngel_LV, Thanks for the link, but i think i should apply animation effect would when user scrolls; i m also in need of scrooling automatically to a childView by a button press,say MENU button,

Comment: @nmxprime Have you try android:fastScrollEnabled="true" property in Listview?

Comment: @DhruvVaishnav, it just shows scrollbar, what i want is the list to scroll to the specified position as like we drag the scroll bar.